# Unable to make a decent query with the combination of BY in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make an sql query which will show the 
number of impressions and clicks by publisher name in the last 7 days. 
So I made the following SQL query. But I'm not sure if it's right. Do you think it will do the things mentioned above? I would love to hear from you!

```
SELECT p.pub_name as "Publisher Name",
       Sum(ast.`impressions`) as 'Impressions', 
       Sum(ast.`clicks`) as "Clicks"
FROM  App_data  ast
Inner JOIN Publishers p 
WHERE  date >= Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 7 day) 
GROUP  BY p.pub_name;
```

I got 3 types of tables

```
1. “Publishers”
[columns]
pub_id
pub_name
pub_country

2. “applications” -  Each publisher (from table #1), can have more than one application

[columns]
app_id
app_name
app_pub_id
App_plat


3. Table name: App_data -  The table holds aggregative data
[columns]
App_id
Date
Impressions 
Clicks
Country
```

Comment: You need an `ON` condition for your tables.

Comment: You also need to join with the `applications` table, so you can relate the `app_data` to the corresponding publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join all 3 tables, since the `applications` table is the link to relate `app_data` to the corresponding `publisher` row. Then you can use `ON` clauses to link the tables.

```
SELECT p.pub_name as "Publisher Name",
       Sum(ast.`impressions`) as 'Impressions', 
       Sum(ast.`clicks`) as "Clicks"
FROM  App_data  ast
INNER JOIN applications app ON ast.app_id = app.app_id
Inner JOIN Publishers p ON p.pub_id = app.pub_id
WHERE  date >= Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 7 day) 
GROUP  BY p.pub_name;
```